# openerp 7 functional field

Tags: python, field, openerp-7

I am trying to create a functional field by inheriting the `account.invoice.line` table, but I cant seem to get it working.  Here is the python code

```
class account_invoice_line(orm.Model):

    _name = 'account.invoice.line'
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'

    _columns = {        
        'calc_qty': fields.function(_get_calc_qty, type="float", string="Quantity", store=False),
    }

    def _get_calc_qty(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        calc_qty = {'qty': 0.0}
        return calc_qty
```

and here is the xml view code

```
    <record id="view_account_invoice_custom_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Account Invoice Form Inherited</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Invoice Lines']/field[@name='invoice_line']/tree/field[@name='quantity']" position="replace">
                <field name="calc_qty" />
            </xpath>

        </field>
    </record>
```

Now I dont want to store this value in the table, but I would like to show the calculated number in the view.  I know this is possible, but after I install the module and then check the invoices form then I get this message

View error

> Can't find field 'calc_qty' in the following view parts composing the view of object model 'account.invoice':
>   * Account Invoice Form Inherited
>
> Either you wrongly customized this view, or some modules bringing those views are not compatible with your current data model

Comment: Well I found out what the problem was.  It had nothing to do with this code above, but instead it was related to the __init__.py file.  I forgot to add the import for the python file in the __init__.py file so the field wasn't being created at all

Comment: function must be come first before _columns = {} Otherwise you will be get error like function not found "your function name"

Comment: Function definition must comes before the function calling line. in your case define you function before the _columns.